# Save Email Upon Send in Outlook Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm making an Outlook Add-in (Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0, C#), and I would like to automatically archive a user's email after they send it. What I have so far is the following:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //Create an event handler for when items are sent
   Application.ItemSend += new ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(saveEmail);
}


private void saveEmail(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
}
```

What I've found through debugging is that my saveEmail method fires off right before the email actually sends. This is OK, ideally I would like it to be fired off immediately after the email is sent successfully, so if there's a way to do that I'd appreciate some pointers.

In any case, I can get inside that method and what I'd like to do is access that email as an Outlook.MailItem object and use the .SaveAs method with whatever parameters I choose. How would I go about grabbing the currently-opened-and-about-to-be-sent-email as a MailItem object?

Comment: This way, the saved email will be showing as un-send email. A better way is to handle `ItemAdd` event of the Sent Mail folder, and save the mail actually got saved there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with this code

```
private void saveEmail(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
         var msg = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
         msg.SaveAs(yourPath, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Candie, and thank you for your edit cjk!

Comment: I'am happy to help you user774359