# Outlook Add on for Hyperlink recognition

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Hello I am looking to create an Add-On (plug in) for Outlook 2010. I have many emails that have an ID number embedded in plain text, these I would like to turn into hyperlinks to a webpage.

The questions I have are:

-Does the Outlook API support this text replacement in already written emails (essentially a regular word replaced by a hyperlink)

-Does something like this already exist?

-This would be my first Outlook Add-On, any good tutorials, basic setup resources?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most certainly do this. I'm just now finishing up my first Outlook add-in, it can be a little daunting at first because the documentation isn't that great, but it shouldn't be too difficult for you. The main question for you to think about is whether or not you want this plugin to be run just once and batch replace every ID number with a hyperlink, or whether you want it to be run on new emails as soon as they're sent...or both.

If the answer is "only new emails", check out the [question I just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040239/save-email-upon-send-in-outlook-add-in), together with the answer you should be able to do something like:

```
String content = msg.Body;
content = content.Replace("123456", "<a href=\"url\">123456</a>");
msg.Body = content;
```

(you could probably do this in one line)

If you want to run through all of the emails in the user's inbox, you're going to need a foreach loop to go through everything in that folder, and run the code above on every email.

I'd suggest starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191) for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Outlook API support this text replacement in already written emails (essentially a regular word replaced by a hyperlink)

Yes it does. You can replace the content of an email with whatever you like, which makes sense because the user would have added your add-on to the trust center.

Not sure if something like this already exists, but for tutorials, googling should help find some good ones ;)